# Dask Read Data from Binary File

Tags: python

I am trying to implement an out of core processing version of k-means clustering algorithm in python. I learned about dask from this git project [K-Mean Parallel](https://github.com/jiteshjha/Kmeans-parallel)... [Dask](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/08/14/out-of-core-dataframes-in-python/)...

I use the same git project but am trying to load my data which is in the form of a binary file. The binary file contains data points with 1024 floating point features each.

My problem is how do I load data if it is very huge i.e. larger than the available memory itself? I tried to use the numpy's fromFile function but my kernel somehow dies. Some of my questions are:

> Q. Is it possible to load data into numpy created from some other source (the file was not created by numpy but a c script)?

---

> Q. Is there a module for dask that can load data directly from a binary file? I have seen csv files used but nothing related to binary files.

Answer (score 1):

I only dabble in Dask, but calling np.fromfile in the code below via Dask delayed should allow you to work with it lazily.  That said, I'm working on this myself so this is currently a partial answer.

For your first question: I currently load .bin files created by a Labview program with no issues using similar code to this:

```
import numpy as np
method = "b+r"  # binary read method
chunkSize = 1e6 # chunk as needed for your purposes
fileSize = os.path.getsize(myfile) 
data = []
with open(myfile,method) as file:
    for chunk in range(0,fileSize,chunkSize):
        data.append(np.fromfile(file,dtype=np.float32,chunk))
```

For the second question: I have not been able to find anything in Dask for dealing with binary files.  I find that a conversion to something that Dask can use, is worth it.

Comment: As shown in [this dask blog post](https://blog.dask.org/2019/06/20/load-image-data) it would be possible to maked `dask.delayed` objects from individual files. However, it may not be straightforward to chunk it as show in this answer.